# How do I escape a single quote in an RFT String in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, string, rtf

In my (c#)-Code I simply replace ' with '' in any strings, this works well with normal strings but not with RTF, any suggestions for a solution which works for both(normal and RTF)?

Thanks
florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
```